# Trouble with multithreading python

Tags: python, multithreading

Having a lot of trouble adding an additional thread to this program'.  As it sits it accesses an  API and executes trades on an account.  All fine and good until I try and pass a streaming rate to the stopLoss order.  Once I run it this way the code runs a loop blocking out everything else and just prints the latest price.  How can I set this thing to run concurrently with the other two threads?

Main trading program:

```
import Queue
import threading
import time
import json
import streamer


from execution import Execution
from settings import STREAM_DOMAIN, API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID
from strategy import TestRandomStrategy
from streaming import StreamingForexPrices
from event import TickEvent
from streamer import demo

stop = demo(0)


def trade(events, strategy, execution):
    """
    Carries out an infinite while loop that polls the
    events queue and directs each event to either the
    strategy component of the execution handler. The
    loop will then pause for "heartbeat" seconds and
    continue.
    """
    while True:
        try:
            event = events.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if event is not None:
                if event.type == 'TICK':
                    strategy.calculate_signals(event)
                elif event.type == 'ORDER':
                    print "Executing order!"
                    execution.execute_order(event)
                elif event.type == 'stopLoss':
                    print "StOP LOSS HERE!!!!"
                    execution.execute_order(event)
        time.sleep(heartbeat)






if __name__ == "__main__":
    heartbeat = 0  # Half a second between polling
    events = Queue.Queue()





    # Trade 1000 unit of EUR/USD

    instrument = "EUR_USD"
    units = 1
    stopLoss = stop




    # Create the OANDA market price streaming class
    # making sure to provide authentication commands
    prices = StreamingForexPrices(
        STREAM_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID,
        instrument, events
    )
    #handle stopLoss price
    stop = demo(0)

    # Create the execution handler making sure to
    # provide authentication commands
    execution = Execution(API_DOMAIN, ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCOUNT_ID)

    # Create the strategy/signal generator, passing the
    # instrument, quantity of units and the events queue
    strategy = TestRandomStrategy(instrument, units, events, stopLoss)

    # Create two separate threads: One for the trading loop
    # and another for the market price streaming class
    trade_thread = threading.Thread(target=trade, args=(events, strategy, execution))
    price_thread = threading.Thread(target=prices.stream_to_queue, args=[])
    stop_thread = threading.Thread(target=stop, args=[])


    # Start both threads
    trade_thread.start()
    price_thread.start()
    stop_thread.start()
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit:
Ok I have drilled down to the problem I think.  This code here executes the trades and when I try and post "prices" to the stopLoss order the script gives me error.  example:

```
stopLoss = prices      NameError: name 'prices' is not defined
```

On the other hand, in trying to simplify the problem to post here I solved another one I was having!

code:

```
def trade(events, strategy, execution):

    while True:
        prices = demo(0)
        print prices

    while True:
        try:
            event = events.get(False)
        except Queue.Empty:
            pass
        else:
            if event is not None:
                if event.type == 'TICK':
                    strategy.calculate_signals(event)
                elif event.type == 'ORDER':
                    print "Executing order!"
                    execution.execute_order(event)
        time.sleep(heartbeat)




if __name__ == "__main__":
    heartbeat = 0  # Half a second between polling
    events = Queue.Queue()

    # Trade 1000 unit of EUR/USD

    instrument = "EUR_USD"
    units = 1
    stopLoss = prices
```

Comment: Can you reduce this to a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Let me see what I can do..

Comment: tzaman, I don't think I can without adding all of the other modules, which I am totally wiling to do..

Comment: The point is more to localize _where specifically_ your problem is than to include everything needed to run it; as your problem stands, you're asking people to read and understand a lot of code before being able to help. Can you at least include pointers / comments inside the code that pinpoint where things are getting stuck?

Comment: Ok, Tzaman, I have evaporated as much as I can and in the process figured out a big part of my problem.  I can now get the prices to print along with the "Tick" data in real time and that is a very good thing!